# Using match_parent in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Is it ok if we use `match_parent` in ConstraintLayout when we don't need any "constrainting"?

For example :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

can be simplified to :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: It is OK. Do you want to know which has advantage?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defeats the purpose of constraint, you should probably use a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout if you are to use the 2nd approach. The goal of ConstraintLayout is to minimize sub levels / sub nests of layouts inside an XML (none of that multiple LinearLayouts or RelativeLayouts anymore instead we can use Groups or ConstraintLayout Flow)

Comment: All the answer is right, but your statment "The goal of ConstraintLayout is to minimize sub levels" make it better than others for me. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help! Parent view should as much as possible be solo or less w/ ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 1):

It's totally okay while using constraints is generally better idea if match_parent gives you same outcome you should go for it cause its less clutter. But in the end it's just the personal preference and doesn't really matter that much.

Answer (score 1):

Read **[Build a Responsive UI](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)**

> The best way to create a responsive layout for different screen sizes
>   is to use ConstraintLayout as the base layout in your UI.
>   ConstraintLayout allows you to specify the position and size for each
>   view according to spatial relationships with other views in the
>   layout. This way, all the views can move and stretch together as the
>   screen size changes.

Both layout's are right. Each layout has its own benefits but when it comes to complex, dynamic and responsive views you should always choose ***Constraint Layout***.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

**OLD**

```
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

**NEW**

```
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```